# How to I .append() user input inside a <div> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a contact card appear on the screen with the name that a user inputs into a  tag.

This would require me to make a  tag for the background color and size and then .append() the user's input inside of that div. It would also require the ability to click the button again and create a second or third contact card with unique information on it.

HTML...

```
<form>
     <h3>First name: <input id="f-name" class="border-rad" type="text"></input></h3>
     <h3>Last name: <input id="l-name" class="border-rad" type="text"></input></h3>
     <h3 id="description-h3">Description:</h3>
     <textarea class="border-rad" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
</form>
```

jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#inner-div").append("<div id='contact-cards'>$('#f-name').val())</div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#inner-div").append("<div id='contact-cards'>" + $('#f-name').val() + "</div>");
    });
});
```

In JavaScript "" or '' means string and this is why your code do not works.

```
$("#inner-div").append("<div id='contact-cards'>$('#f-name').val())</div>");
```

You need to get value of variable and concat to string, like this.

```
"<div id='contact-cards'>" + $('#f-name').val() + "</div>"
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you create a new jquery DOM object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#inner-div").append($('<div />', {id: 'contact-cards', text: $('#f-name').val()}));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to separately write **$('#f-name').val()** to prevent it from being treated as string rather than function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    $("#inner-div").append("<div id='contact-cards'>"+$('#f-name').val()+"</div>");
    });
});
```